# How to get from $P [\phi\leftrightarrow \psi]=1$ to $P[\phi]=P[\psi]$

Tags: probability, propositional-calculus

That's the formulas i got

$\begin{align}P[\phi \leftrightarrow \psi] = 1 &\equiv P[(\phi\wedge\psi)\vee(\neg\phi\wedge\neg\psi)] = 1 \\
&\equiv P[\phi\wedge\psi] + P[\neg\phi\wedge \neg\psi] = 1 \\
&\equiv P[\phi\wedge\psi] = 1−P[\neg\phi\wedge\neg\psi] \\
&\equiv P[\phi\wedge\psi] = P[\phi\vee\psi] \\
&\equiv P[\phi\wedge\psi] = P[\phi] + P[\psi]−P[\phi\wedge\psi]\end{align}$

Need some advice on how to proceed

Comment: Your attempt stops making sense when you write $P(\phi\land\psi) = P(\lnot\phi\land\lnot \psi)$... that's not true... (and I'll reiterate my recommendation to draw a venn diagrams from the comment below the answer.)

Comment: Didn't write that my post got edited

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I didn't see that... and that's not the only thing they messed up. I tried to further correct it... hopefully it's back to what you intended now.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $P[\phi] = P[\phi \land \lnot\psi] + P[\phi \land \psi] = P[\phi \land \psi]$.

This lets you, from

$\begin{align}
P[\phi \land \psi] & = P[\phi] + P[\psi] - P[\phi \land \psi]\\
                   & = P[\phi \land \psi] + P[\psi] - P[\phi \land \psi]\\
                   & = P[\psi]
\end{align}$

Now do the replacement on the other side to get $P[\phi] = P[\psi]$.

Comment: First off why does that hold? And how could i use that? I don't get that one. =P[ϕ∧ψ] .

Comment: P[ϕ∧¬ψ]+P[ϕ∧ψ]=P[ϕ∧ψ]

Comment: @Rapiz Because $\phi=\phi\land \top = \phi\land(\psi\lor\lnot\psi)$ and $(\phi\land\psi)\land(\phi\land\lnot\psi)=\bot$ . In general I think you'll find it more profitable to draw venn-diagrams than to stab at it algebraically.

Comment: If $\phi$ is true, then $\psi$ is either true or false. Also $P[\phi \land \lnot \psi] = 0$, by assumption.

Comment: How could i use that one in my equations?

Comment: @Rapiz It applies to the equations in my answer, not in your equations. I don't think your equations are the right way to proceed, or at least they make the problem harder than it needs to be.

Comment: But i have to start at P[ϕ↔ψ]=1 and bring that to P[ϕ] =  P[ψ] don't know how to do that with your equations